# how to get correct value from multiple select with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple select html tag in one page,and I would like get two values when user click the dropdown list.
But,I have a little problem with my script.
It seems like have a loop bug,and I don't know how to find it out.

[FIDDLER](https://jsfiddle.net/huangmarc/9t9nuuoz/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.SizeSelect').on('click',function(){
    
    var sel = $("#SizeSelect_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('SizeSelect_',''));
    
    sel.data("preValue",sel.val());
    
    sel.change(function(){
      var th = $(this);
      th.data("newValue",th.val());
      
      //output
      $('#log').append('pre:'+th.data("preValue")+' / select:'+th.data("newValue")+'<br/>');
    
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<select id="SizeSelect_14" class="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelectName">
    <option value="5">N/A3</option>
    <option value="101">N/A2</option>
    <option value="105">N/A1</option>
</select>

<select id="SizeSelect_15" class="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelectName">
    <option value="6">2N/A3</option>
    <option value="102">2N/A2</option>
    <option value="106">2N/A1</option>
</select>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this` element which invoked the event and use `.off()` to unbind the previous event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.SizeSelect').on('click', function() {

    var sel = $(this);
    sel.data("preValue", sel.val());
    sel.off('change').on('change', function() {
      var th = $(this);
      th.data("newValue", th.val());

      //output
      $('#log').append('pre:' + th.data("preValue") + ' / select:' + th.data("newValue") + '<br/>');

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SizeSelect_14" class="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelectName">
  <option value="5">N/A3</option>
  <option value="101">N/A2</option>
  <option value="105">N/A1</option>
</select>

<select id="SizeSelect_15" class="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelectName">
  <option value="6">2N/A3</option>
  <option value="102">2N/A2</option>
  <option value="106">2N/A1</option>
</select>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add change and click like the above code. You need to trigger only the change event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.SizeSelect').on('change',function(){

    var sel = $("#SizeSelect_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('SizeSelect_',''));

    sel.data("preValue",sel.val());


      var th = $(this);
      th.data("newValue",th.val());

      //output
      $('#log').append('pre:'+th.data("preValue")+' / select:'+th.data("newValue")+'<br/>');

  });

});
```

Check the fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/Y3pW9/729/)